# Make button act like checked box, knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

So basically I have a button on my html which has a small js on it which onclick turns the button green and when clicked again turns the button grey to make it feel like its turning on and off. Here is the JS and the HTML code for the button

```
<script>
$('#button1').click(function() {
    //Now just reference this button and change CSS
     $(this).toggleClass('buttonClassA');
});
</script>

<button type="button" class="col-md-2 notice-btns btn " id="button1">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <p data-bind="if : $data.emailNotification == 1 ">On</p>
            <p data-bind="if : $data.emailNotification == 0 ">Off</p>
          </button>
```

I have two knockout function which needs to be called when the button is clicked
which are

```
self.emailNotification = ko.observable(); 
        self.turnOnEmailNotification = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: BASEURL + 'index.php/myprofile/checkNotificationValue/' + auth  + "/" + self.emailNotification(1) ,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            })
            .done(function(notifications) {
                self.emailNotification.removeAll();
                self.emailNotification.push(notifications);
            })
            .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(status);
            })
            .always(function(data){                 
            });
        };

        self.turnOffEmailNotification = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: BASEURL + 'index.php/myprofile/checkNotificationValue/' + auth  + "/" + self.emailNotification(0) ,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            })
            .done(function(notifications) {
                self.emailNotification.removeAll();
                self.emailNotification.push(notifications);
            })
            .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(status);
            })
            .always(function(data){                 
            });
        };
```

I tried the data-bind checked but then i lose the buttons so need help to call both the ajax calls

> $root.turnOnEmailNotification

and

> $root.turnOffEmailNotification

in the same button and so I can give it a feeling its turning on and off.

Answer (score 1):

`Checked` isn't a valid attribute for button element .Instead you can use `click` to achieve the same via toggling .

**view:**

```
<button type="button" data-bind="click:tgle,style:{'background-color':emailNotification()==0 ? 'red':'green'}">
<p data-bind="text:$data.emailNotification() == 1 ? 'On' : 'Off' "></p>
</button>
```

**viewModel:**

```
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.emailNotification = ko.observable(0);
  self.tgle = function() {
    self.emailNotification(self.emailNotification() == 1 ? 0 : 1)
    switch (self.emailNotification()) {
      case 0:
        console.log('turn off ajax fired');
        //turnOFFEmailNotification 
        //$.ajax({
        //  Do ajax stuff               
        //});
        break;
      case 1:
        console.log('turn on ajax fired');
        //turnOnEmailNotification //default off
        //$.ajax({
        //  Do ajax stuff               
        //});
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

working sample up for **[grabs](https://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/29278/)**

Comment: Hey I tried it your way, looks like its working but the problem is when ajax is fired it doesnt actually do the POST method but only returns an error

Comment: @Farhana issue with ajax call is independent with the code i see . share your error in console

Comment: @Farhana you use a simple GET rather using POST as your are not passing anything in request body .

Comment: That pair of `if` bindings is pretty awful. A single `text` would be more appropriate. (I realize it comes from the original post)

Comment: @supercool hey your function works, I fixed it finally, but there is one problem, when I refresh the page then it returns back to the same thing, what is the best solution to get the value from the database to show on the button untill changed ?

Comment: @Farhana yup it will always return the default setting because i'm using `self.emailNotification = ko.observable(0);` here i gave `0` which is `OFF` irrespective of your db value onLoad . instead seting  `0` or `1` value to emailNotification static you can  make a similar ajax request onLoad and set the value to it inside success . hope that's clear